# For loop only gives last result of for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I wanted to print out datas until list_3 is ended. But, no matter how I tried, I only got last result of list_3. Here's my code:

```
import FinanceDataReader as fdr 
import numpy as np
from numpy import NaN
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl 
....

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format


file_list = os.listdir('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel')

list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 =[ 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022 ] 




for i in range(10): 



os.chdir('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel')
odd = file_list[i]

td = pd.read_excel('/home/sejahui/projects/stock_data_excel/'+str(odd))
td['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(td['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d' )



   for r in range(12):
      target_year = list_3[r]



data = td.query('Date.dt.year == @target_year')

'''
td['Year'] = td['Date'].dt.year
data = td.groupby(['Year'])
'''


def calMACD(data, short=5, long=25, signal=9):
    data.sort_index()
    
    data['MVA_25']=data['Close'].ewm(span=long, adjust=False).mean()
    data['MVA_5']=data['Close'].ewm(span=short, adjust=False).mean()
    data['MACD']=data['Close'].ewm(span=short, adjust=False).mean() - data['Close'].ewm(span=long, adjust=False).mean()
    data['Signal']=data['MACD'].ewm(span=signal, adjust=False).mean( )
    #data['Buy_sign']=(data['MACD']-data['Signal']) >=600
    data['Buy_sign']=np.where(data['MACD']-data['Signal'] >=451, 'Buy' , 'Sell' )
    #data['Target_1']=(data['Close']-data['Close'].shift(1))/data['Close'].shift(1)*100
    #data['Target_1']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Buy', (data['Change'])+1,1)
    #data['Target_2']=np.where(data['Buy_sign']=='Sell', (data['Change'])+1,1)
    #data['Real_world']= 1000000*data['Target_1']
    #data['Real_world_2']= 1000000*data['Target_2'] 
    #data['Condition'] = np.where(data['Real_world']<1000000, data['Real_world']-data['Real_world'].shift(-2),1)
    ##data['Condition_2'] = np.where(data['Real_world']<1000000, data['Target_1'].shift(-2),1)
    #data['Moneyflow'] = 
    #plt.plot(data['Date'], data['Real_world'])
    #data[data.Buy_sign !='Sell']
    
    


    return data
print(calMACD(data), odd)
```

I tried to get results with for loop in for loop, but, second for loop only gives the last result of for loop. What changes should I make to get all the results of second for loop?

※note: the second for loop indentation might looks uncorrect, but, it works perfectly fine without any error.

Comment: Your first `for` loop is executing no instructions and your second `for` loop is executing one instruction: `target_year = list_3[r]`. Indent your code properly. And delete unnecessary blank lines.

Comment: Sorry for the visual of first for loop. It looks like it works alone, however, it gives i value to line of codes of its bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with not having `td.query('Date.dt.year == @target_year')` in for loop scope, move the query part in for loop scope to get all the target_year processed.

```
for r in range(12):
    target_year = list_3[r]
    data = td.query('Date.dt.year == @target_year')
```

Also, you can optimized it to

```
for target_year in list_3:
    data = td.query('Date.dt.year == @target_year')
```

Comment: Thank you for your code! I fixed my problem. But, another problem pops up. for i in range(10) is for bring datas in ODD list. However it only brings the data which entered sequence number. How can I bring all sequence datas?